# Unable to run specific spec file using protractor

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to organize the "test files" into folders and run a specific spec file using protractor . For that i created below files.

heroes_spec.js file contains below code

```
var HeroesHomePage = require('C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\VSCodeWorkSpace\my-app\e2e\Heroes\heros_po.js');

describe('Heroes page tests' , function(){
    var heroespage = new HeroesHomePage();
    heroespage.heroesLinkClickEvent();
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
});
```

hero_po.js file contains below code

```
var heroesLinkClickEvent;

var hero_page = function() {
    this.heroesLinkClickEvent= function(){
    element(by.linkText('Heroes')).click();
  }
};
hero_po.js is as below
module.exports = hero_page;
```

My protractor.conf.js file code is below

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
   suites: {
    heroespage : 'C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\VSCodeWorkSpace\my-app\e2e\Heroes\heroes_spec.js'
  },
  capabilities: 
   { 
     'browserName': 'chrome',
     'seleniumAddress':'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
   },    
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    includeStackTrace: true
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });    
  },
}
```

When i run protractor protractor.conf.js --suite heroespage command after starting "selenium server".

No specs found message is displaying.
Can any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure the path `C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\VSCodeWorkSpace\my-app\e2e\Heroes\heroes_spec.js` is correct?

Comment: If you want to run just one suite test, you can try with **fdescribe** https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.8/global.html#fdescribe

Comment: yes C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\VSCodeWorkSpace\my-app\e2e\Heroes\he‌​roes_spec.js is correct  i right click on the file name under "e2e" folder and copy the path by clicking "copy path" option

Comment: i want to run multiple spec files , at this time i gave only one spec file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Give relative path to your project root folder.**

```
 suites: {
    heroespage: ['e2e\Heroes\heroes_spec.js']
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware, that Javascript uses forward-slashes `/` for paths and not backslashes `\`?

With a backslash you basically just exit the next character.

So try either with `/` instead of `\`

```
heroespage : 'C:/Users/agudla/Desktop/VSCodeWorkSpace/my-app/e2e/Heroes/heroes_spec.js'
```

Do this in all your paths within Protractor.

That should do the trick.

Comment: i tried with above two mentioned options , it is displaying "Cannot find module 'C:UsersagudlaDesktopVSCodeWorkSpacemy-appe2eHeroesheros_po.js'" error message

Comment: Do all paths with `/` instead backslash. The nackslash is Windows... Protractor is not. So `heroes_spec.js` and `protractor.conf.js` and evtl. more of those.

Comment: Protractor automatically takes path till your project root. If you have spec files inside a folder under root project folder then this worked for me:                                        specs: ['Tests/TC002.js']

Answer (score 0):

This is the command passed:

```
protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js --specs src/test/javascript/e2e/entities\points\points.spec.t
s
```

which is protractor conf files and then command line parameters followed by value.